# how to code something that requires printing with lines

Tags: python, function, line

`a` is a parameter in `def star(a)`

I have to define a `def` and coding.

Im asking  `a= int(input("what is a?:  ")`.

For example if `a` is `3`:
first line has one sign,
second line has two sign,
third line has 3 sign and done.

```py
def star(a):
    #idk
    return #dk
a=int(input("a is a:  "))
print("Shape:  ", star(a))
```

Comment: i spent 20 minutes to ask the question and my codes doesn't look right.

Comment: so, how can i make it look right?

Comment: use ` not quotes. Different symbol.

Comment: What do you mean by "sign"? What happens if `a=4`? There will be a forth line with for signs?

Comment: I meant sign '*' i tried to print this as a symbol. If a=4 happens, there will be forth line yes, with four signs.

Answer (score 0):

You can just multiply strings in python using `*`!

```
def print_line(number_of_signs):
    print("*"*number_of_signs+1) # plus one since it otherwise prints 0 starts at first iteration


a = int(input("a is a: "))
for line in range(a):
    print_line(line)
```

If you want the stars to start in the middle, you should add some logic in `print_line` to form a string, than print that string.

edit: added +1 in `print_line` to deal with the first iteration being 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't the clearest, but I'll try to answer nonetheless.

```py
def star(a):
    # Will only work if a is odd
    if (a % 2) == 0:
        print("a should be odd!")
        return None

    output = ""  # Final output string
    for i in range(1, a + 1, 2):                                     # This represents the number of signs per line, must always be odd so start at 1 and increment by 2
        padding = int((a - i) / 2)                                   # This is the padding on either side of the signs

        line = (" " * padding) + ("-" * i) + (" " * padding) + "\n"  # Create the line, \n creates a new line

        output += line                                               # Add the line to the final output

    return output


a = int(input("a > "))
print(star(a))
```

Output:

```
a > 5
  -  
 --- 
-----
```

Is that what you were going for?